# Where should I place my inline data table buttons?

Tags: user-expectation, desktop-application, data-tables

I'm building a desktop application with the intent for my users to perform action items on remote devices (can't say due to company IP). Users will also check the status of these devices, pre and post action.

I have a data table with all of the fields that users will need to check. See image below. My action items are located above the data table. Each entry in the data table also has two inline buttons, one for additional information (left hand side), and another one to remove the device from the table (right hand side).

[image: snapshot of data table]

The company really would like our users to perform the action items (not shown) on all of the remote devices at once, so for that reason I have not considered adding a checkbox to the data table to avoid confusion.

My question is: Am I using the best design here for my inline buttons? I am only showing about 70% of the fields, and the data table does become pretty wide. Although, if the user is using the app full-screen, it is always easy to see all the content in the table. Would it be preferable to have my inline buttons next to each other, either both on the right or both on the left, or am I going crazy just over-analyzing this?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inline Button/Call to Action Buttons Should Be available in same Column of the row. no need to give it in two different columns. Also on Button Hover you can provide information. which generally refers to "Tooltips". 
[image: Inline Call to Action Buttons]

Also don't gray out whole Row on hover, if it's required then go for lighter color shade, this resembles to call for to disabled row or giving odd vibes of user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Of course next to each other and as close as possible to the mouse hand. 
The shorter the user's travel on the screen, the better the interface design.

You are forcing the user to visualize a pattern of lines, something visually tedious, if on top you make them go from one side to another to interact with the respective buttons, it makes the situation worse.

Comment: It is not always necessarily the best to put actions as close to each other as possible, since you often want the action next to the piece of information that you are using to make the decision. Sometimes lessening the amount of travel on the screen with the mouse means more travel on the screen with the eyes of the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to over-analyze the scenario and end up not being able to make the best decision. Here are some potential things you can consider in making the initial decision, and then based on feedback or testing from the users you can further tweak the design.

- Consider the relationship between the actions and the information on the table cell when grouping them (i.e. which pieces of information do you look at before making certain actions, or which values do you expect to change after making certain actions)
- Consider the amount of movement of the mouse for common use cases
- Consider the amount of scanning across the table for common use cases
- Prioritize the information you show/display based on best and worst case scenarios
- Consider future changes to the contents that you might have to cater for